# awk sed multiple rows and create column from variable pattern

Tags: awk, sed, row, multiple-columns

hi awkers i achieved formating text to this following form in order to process it

```
HEADLINE01;INTRO;0X555
;A;0X22;;3;device:notebook;
;SPORT;round:;overcome
;FOO;set:;123456
;B;0X21;;3;device:charger;
;SPORT;round:;otherside
;FOO;set:;465465
INFO;INTRO;0X554
;O;0X23;;8;device:pc;
;SPORT;round:;overcome
;FOO;set:;123456
;N;0X24;;13;device:infra;
;SPORT;round:;otherside
;FOO;set:;465465
```

and cannot find the way how to achieve this

```
HEADLINE01;INTRO;0X555;A;0X22;;3;device:notebook;;SPORT;round:;overcome;FOO;set:;123456
HEADLINE01;INTRO;0X555;B;0X21;;3;device:charger;;SPORT;round:;otherside;FOO;set:;465465
INFO;INTRO;0X554;O;0X23;;8;device:pc;;SPORT;round:;overcome;FOO;set:;123456
INFO;INTRO;0X554;N;0X24;;13;device:infra;;SPORT;round:;otherside;FOO;set:;465465
```

its a lot of rows and cannot format it to proper way

i also tranformed that as well to  one row but then splitting based on pattern "HEADLINE01" or "INFO" is not working for me as its changing with ongoing other rows

any trick i will appreciate

// original format processed is this one

```
------------------------------BOOKING LOG-----------------------------------
lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum
-----------------------------------------------------------------
BOOKING:ENTRY:SYSTEM# SCAN
result:
No entry is found!
BOOKING:ENTRY::SYSTEM# SCAN
BOOKING:ENTRY::SYSTEM# SCAN
output:
system entry is:
  date sytem log year 
  HEADLINE01   INTRO  0X555 
  log output list: 56456 lines 
    system device data transfer echoed NOK
    A    0X22;      3;device:notebook
        XX: BASE 
        SPORT round: overcome
        FOO set: 465465
```

....
....

thank you, with moving this forward

code is following:

```
$ perl -ane 'print "$F[0] $F[1] $F[2]\n"' log | grep -E "^{1,5}HEADLINE01|A |SPORT|FOO" | sed -e 's/A /;A;/g; s/ /;/g; s/FOO/;FOO/g; s/SPORT/;SPORT/g;'


HEADLINE01;INTRO;0X555
;A;0X22;;3;device:notebook
;SPORT;round:;overcome
;FOO;set:;465465
```

Comment: please add your code that does the transformation you mentioned.  You may just need a few formatting changes to achieve the desired result.

Comment: hi code is following,
$ perl -ane 'print "$F[0] $F[1] $F[2]\n"' log | grep -E "^{1,5}HEADLINE01|A |SPORT|FOO" | sed -e 's/A /;A;/g; s/ /;/g; s/FOO/;FOO/g; s/SPORT/;SPORT/g;'


HEADLINE01;INTRO;0X555
;A;0X22;;3;device:notebook
;SPORT;round:;overcome
;FOO;set:;465465

Comment: Code in comments are not readable; if you started with `perl` why switch to `awk` at this point?

Comment: well i tried to traspose it via and stucked on this:

awk -F';' '{ for(i=1;i<=7;i++) print $0 $1,$2,$i,$4 }' OFS='' log via this one , but need to remove that duplicity

but i am on wrong one direction as its printing multiply this records and then to transpose them back to columns, perl was used as one option as have awk one too and trying to get it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

ideally you can write the full conversion program in one `awk` script.  Second best is to convert the intermediate format to the desired output.

```
$ awk -F'\n' -v RS='(\n|^)[A-Z]+' -v OFS='' '
           NR>1 {print rt $1,$2,$3,$4; 
                 print rt $1,$5,$6,$7} 
                {rt=RT; sub("\n","",rt)}' file

HEADLINE01;INTRO;0X555;A;0X22;;3;device:notebook;;SPORT;round:;overcome;FOO;set:;123456
HEADLINE01;INTRO;0X555;B;0X21;;3;device:charger;;SPORT;round:;otherside;FOO;set:;465465
INFO;INTRO;0X554;O;0X23;;8;device:pc;;SPORT;round:;overcome;FOO;set:;123456
INFO;INTRO;0X554;N;0X24;;13;device:infra;;SPORT;round:;otherside;FOO;set:;465465
```

note that this requires `gawk`s multi-char RS support.

Comment: it works like a charm i needed to convert first input file into proper unix format, now i can use it on several logs structures, like this, thank you karakfa for your patience and support in my exploration work with text processing, thanks

Comment: i get it work partially with added loop 


for ((i = 3; i <= 10; i++)); do gawk -F'\n' -v RS='(\n|^)[A-Z]+' -v OFS='' ' NR>1 {print rt $1,$2,$3,$4; print rt $1,$5,$6,$7;} {rt=RT; sub("\n","",rt)}' rows ; done        

but "print rt $1,$2,$ ..:" is still fixed to print per to lines only instead of until beginining of next pattern INFO or same one HEADLINE01

Comment: didn't understand the comment.  It's going to keep the same fields as prefix; that's how your sample input/output is.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid Carriage return/Linefeeds use printf:

```
awk '{ printf("%s",$0) }'
```

Comment: yes i have it as well in "one line" output but cannot achieve desired output in formated colums as desribed in upper section / above